# Laravel 5.6 Changing Breadcrumb Language

Tags: laravel, internationalization, laravel-5.6, breadcrumbs

i am having problem to switch the wording language on Breadcrumbs in Laravel 5.6

the code of my breadcrumbs inside my layouts file are

`{{ Breadcrumbs::render('home') }}`

the rendered function are located at `\routes\breadcrumbs.php`

below

```
Breadcrumbs::register('home', function ($breadcrumbs) {
    $breadcrumbs->push('Home', route('home'));
});
```

where do i put the keywords to change the breadcrumbs based on language currently active as i usually just put
`@lang('home.home')` or `{{ __('home.home') }}`
to change the wording language, but breadcrumbs.php aren't .blade file, so cant use the shown type for reading value

Comment: If they aren't `.blade.php` files, you can use regular php expressions to handle, such as `<?php echo e(__('home.home')); ?>`, since `{{ }}` is simply a wrapper for `<?php echo e(...); ?>`. The `__()` (or `trans()`) function should be globally available too.

Comment: Thank you, it works, this problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

example:Laravel 7

```
Breadcrumbs::for('home', function ($trail) {

$home = e(__('home.dashboard'));  //'app/lang/home.php' 

$trail->push( $home , route('home'));
});
```